# how do i print letters like AAA001 to zzz999 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I'd like to print the following Series in a console using `c#`

```
AAA000
AAA001
AAA002
.
.
.
AAA999
AAB000
AAB001
.
.
.UPTO
ZZZ999
```

kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way could be:

```
for (int i1 = 'A'; i1 <= 'Z'; i1++)
{
    for (int i2 = 'A'; i2 <= 'Z'; i2++)
    {
        for (int i3 = 'A'; i3 <= 'Z'; i3++)
        {
            for (int i4 = '0'; i4 <= '9'; i4++)
            {
                for (int i5 = '0'; i5 <= '9'; i5++)
                {
                    for (int i6 = '0'; i6 <= '9'; i6++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(new string(new Char[] { (Char)i1, (Char)i2, (Char)i3, (Char)i4, (Char)i5, (Char)i6 }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The key point is in 'A' to 'Z' and '0' to '9' sequence and conversion between int and Char.

Comment: I'm really thankful to you

Answer (score 2):

```
var letters = Enumerable.Range('A', 'Z' - 'A' + 1).Select(i => (char)i);
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
var series =
    from l1 in letters
    from l2 in letters
    from l3 in letters
    from n1 in numbers
    from n2 in numbers
    from n3 in numbers
    select l1.ToString() + l2 + l3 + n1 + n2 + n3;

foreach (string s in series)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reza Aghaei [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32153916/3110834) it very well i have shorten the code by reducing two loops, as like the following:

```
for (int i1 = 'A'; i1 <= 'Z'; i1++)
    {
      for (int i2 = 'A'; i2 <= 'Z'; i2++)
        {
           for (int i3 = 'A'; i3 <= 'Z'; i3++)
              {
                 for (int i4 = 0; i4 <= 999; i4++)
                   { Console.WriteLine(new string(new Char[] { (Char)i1, (Char)i2, (Char)i3 }) + i4.ToString("000"));}
               }
         }
    }
```

`{}` used to improve the readability that also not necessary: simply you will get expected output by using the following:

```
for (int i1 = 'A'; i1 <= 'Z'; i1++)
for (int i2 = 'A'; i2 <= 'Z'; i2++)
for (int i3 = 'A'; i3 <= 'Z'; i3++)
for (int i4 = 0; i4 <= 999; i4++)
Console.WriteLine(new string(new Char[] { (Char)i1, (Char)i2, (Char)i3 }) + i4.ToString("000"));
```